# Cyberpunk. Protagonist was cured from Alzheimer's(?) and is learning how to live in "the Future". Flu is used to modify people's behavior

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

The protagonist finds himself in the future cured from Alzheimer's disease. He lost memories of several decades and now learns how to live in the future (somewhat 2030-2080).

Everyone uses wearable computers built into their clothes.

Flus are used as a weapon and to change people behavior, e.g. to modify how people react to ads.

There are some agencies tracking flus all over the world.

I also remember that the protagonist is struggling to fix his relationship with his family. Everything ends in some underground with melted metal/stone where he trying to save his granddaughter(?).

Comment: Been a while since I read it and I remember less 'flu and more augmented reality, but the lost decades/Alzheimer's/family relationships thing sounds like Vernor Vinge's "Rainbows End". Will check and post a proper answer later.

Comment: Yes. Thats it. Or at least one of those stories which are mesing up in my head. There is a chance, that the all flu stuff is from somewhere else.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's an Ian McDonald bell going off in my brain, I'm not going to have time to check it out today though, sorry.

Comment: I came here to answer *Rainbow's End*, but I see it's already identified.  It's set in 2025.  Miri is Robert's granddaughter...

Comment: Hmm, looks like I was beaten to it in posting a full answer...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is certainly *Rainbows End* by Vernor Vinge.  It matches pretty much point for point.

The guy brought back from Alzheimer's is the main character and the story deals with him coming to grips with a new world much nearer the Singularity than what he last remembered. He was a poet and prior to his Alzheimer's didn't have a technical bone in his body, but after coming back, his mind seems improved and he now has new technical skills as well.

The computers-in-clothing gives him a bit of trouble, but he decides to adapt and learn the gesture language used to control them.

The *other* protagonist as an AI who is lurking in the sidelines and seems to be generally helpful, if occasionally prone to bits of mischief.  (Like leaving carrots that can't be removed on people vistual desktops.)

(Two other great scenes: One, when the AI *walks* the UCSD Library building and the other where the cyber security agencies discover the AI and try to kill it by revoking root certificates.)

The underground part is when his granddaughter -- I think -- is taken by terrorists and held in an underground (literally) lab in San Diego. The US military used orbital lasers to melt into the lab and the good guys are saved.

It's a brilliant book by one of the masters.